# Cannot convert undefined value to object - React native with expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I want to use navigator for my app and im using expo to work on my project: this is my App.js:

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import LoginPage from "./components/LoginPage";
import MainComponent from "./components/MainComponent";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

const App = () => {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

    // <LoginPage></LoginPage>
  );
};

export default App;
```

the error comes from -> const Stack = createStackNavigator(); it says cannot convert undefined value to object, i tried to follow up with documentation but not going anywhere. Any little hint would be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: You should import createStackNavigator  from `@react-navigation/stack`. See [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#api-definition](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#api-definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The way that you import createNativeStackNavigator is wrong.
2. You need to call createNativeStackNavigator outside of your
   component tree.

Try the code below:

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import LoginPage from "./components/LoginPage";
import MainComponent from "./components/MainComponent";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

    // <LoginPage></LoginPage>
  );
};

export default App;
```